# How to update a resulting table from a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table which is a shorter version of my original table. What I have is the following:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM bookings_tbl
where ACCOUNT LIKE 'RENTA%' AND PART_TYPE ='HARDWARE')
SET PART_TYPE= 'EQUIPO' WHERE PART_TYPE='HARDWARE';
```

Don't know if it s possible, but I would like to have what is stated as HARDWARE in that small table saying EQUIPO. I'm using micros SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: put your table schema here.

Comment: `SELECT ACCOUNT, 'EQUIPO' AS PART_TYPE FROM bookings_tbl WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE 'RENTA%' AND PART_TYPE ='HARDWARE'`

Answer (score 1):

You have the `update` construct incorrect. Change it to..

```
UPDATE bookings_tbl
SET PART_TYPE= 'EQUIPO' 
WHERE PART_TYPE='HARDWARE' AND ACCOUNT LIKE 'RENTA%';
```

Comment: but i don t want to update the original table, just the one resulting from the query

Comment: that is what the `where` clause is for. This will update rows which have `PART_TYPE='HARDWARE' AND ACCOUNT LIKE 'RENTA%'` to `PART_TYPE = 'EQUIPO'`

Comment: Please update the post to mention your intention that u don't intend to update the base table of SQL server but actually intend to play with an in memory construct

Answer (score 0):

Use `@table` variable in SQL server . Define the schema of table variable first. Then select all the records that you intend to update and put them into that `@table` variable. Then put your where condition to update the table variable as per your where clause.

`UPDATE @myTableVariable
SET PART_TYPE= 'EQUIPO' 
WHERE PART_TYPE='HARDWARE' AND ACCOUNT LIKE 'RENTA%';`